# WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from ... to ['...']

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Training an image classifier using `.fit_generator()` or `.fit()` and passing a dictionary to `class_weight=` as an argument.

I never got errors in TF1.x but in 2.1 I get the following output when starting training:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
```

What does it mean to coerce something from `...` to `['...']`?

The source for this warning on `tensorflow`'s repo is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d1574c209396d38ebe3c20b3ba1cb4c8d82170ae/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1090), comments placed are:

> Attempt to coerce sample_weight_modes to the target structure. This implicitly depends on the fact that Model flattens outputs for its internal representation.

Comment: Funny to see such a recent question as the only search result for my own warnings as well.

Comment: @jorijnsmit can you provide the code to replicate the issue/warning?

Comment: Actually switching to TF2 with `%tensorflow_version 2.x` is enough to make this warning appear: https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jorijnsmit/9a8fe5020f1c4d6e0c3a4a60329d3083/untitled2.ipynb

Comment: @jorijnsmit, No, I get the same warning but have actually installed TF2.1 as `pip install tensorflow` (within pyenv/virtualenv environment)

Comment: Yes indeed @lurix66, the code that generates this error is introduced in `2.1.0rc0`.

Comment: I got the same warning with TF 2.1. Downgrading to TF 2.0 solved the issue.

Comment: @Seven Up or you could upgrade to TF 2.2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems like a bogus message. I get the same warning message after upgrading to TensorFlow 2.1, but I do not use any class weights or sample weights at all. I do use a generator that returns a tuple like this:

```
return inputs, targets
```

And now I just changed it to the following to make the warning go away:

```
return inputs, targets, [None]
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but my model uses 3 inputs, so my `inputs` variable is actually a list of 3 numpy arrays.  `targets` is just a single numpy array.

In any case, it's just a warning.  The training works fine either way.

## Edit for TensorFlow 2.2:

This bug seems to have been fixed in TensorFlow 2.2, which is great.  However the fix above will fail in TF 2.2, because it will try to get the shape of the sample weights, which will obviously fail with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`.  So undo the above fix when upgrading to 2.2.

Comment: OMG this `AttributeError` was killing me... thank you so much!

Answer (score 20):

I believe this is a bug with tensorflow that will happen when you call `model.compile()` with default parameter `sample_weight_mode=None` and then call `model.fit()` with specified `sample_weight` or `class_weight`.

From the tensorflow repos:

- `fit()` eventually calls `_process_training_inputs()`
- `_process_training_inputs()` [sets](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b7a6d319bb7435ad5ea073b09cd60deddc47c14b/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py#L545) `sample_weight_modes = [None]` based on `model.sample_weight_mode = None` and then creates a `DataAdapter` with `sample_weight_modes = [None]`
- the `DataAdapter` calls `broadcast_sample_weight_modes()` with `sample_weight_modes = [None]` during [initialization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d1574c209396d38ebe3c20b3ba1cb4c8d82170ae/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L652)
- `broadcast_sample_weight_modes()` [seems to expect](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d1574c209396d38ebe3c20b3ba1cb4c8d82170ae/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1074) `sample_weight_modes = None` but receives `[None]`
- it asserts that `[None]` is a different structure from `sample_weight` / `class_weight`, overwrites it back to `None` by fitting to the structure of `sample_weight` / `class_weight` and outputs a warning

Warning aside this has no effect on `fit()` as `sample_weight_modes` in the `DataAdapter` is set back to `None`.

Note that tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) states that `sample_weight` must be a numpy-array. If you call `fit()` with `sample_weight.tolist()` instead, you will not get a warning but `sample_weight` is silently overwritten to `None` when `_process_numpy_inputs()` is called in [preprocessing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d1574c209396d38ebe3c20b3ba1cb4c8d82170ae/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1022) and receives an input of length greater than one.

Comment: A very thorough explanation, thanks. Only thing I don't understand is that the warning describes `...` being coerced to `[...]`, whereas in your case `[None]` is coerced to `None`...

Answer (score 7):

I have taken your Gist and installed Tensorflow 2.0, instead of TFA and it worked without any such Warning.

Here is the [Gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/e9d65d1119d90c1ec0d435249f3f5d01/untitled2.ipynb) of the complete code. Code for installing the Tensorflow is shown below:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

Screenshot of the successful execution is shown below:

[image]

**Update:** This bug is fixed in **`Tensorflow Version 2.2.`**

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right, the warning message is not introduced until version `2.1.0rc0`. However, I'm afraid my question remains: "What does it mean to coerce something from `...` to `['...']`?"

Comment: I noticed that some probably unintended stuff happens when `sample_weight_mode=None` and `target_structure` is of type `dict`, `sample_weight_modes` is then `[None]` and the exception in `broadcast_sample_weight_modes` is caught due to the `dict`. Can this be considered as a bug?

Comment: @FranzKnülle could you elaborate on this in an answer? Not sure if it is the answer to my question but at least worth the bounty!

Comment: @jorijnsmit Did you find any solution to this warning? I've installed the '2.1.0' and also seeing same warning.

Comment: Nope. Question keeps gathering views and upvotes but no answers.

Comment: I had a look and came to the same conclusion as @FranzKnülle - think it is a bug

Comment: @gkennos: If you feel it is a bug, Can you file a Bug in Github Tensorflow Repository.

Comment: It's definitely a bug, but it's now fixed in TensorFlow 2.2

Answer (score 4):

instead of providing a dictionary

```
weights = {'0': 42.0, '1': 1.0}
```

i tried a list

```
weights = [42.0, 1.0]
```

and the warning disappeared.

Comment: Thanks man! I was trying (unsuccessful) with dictionaries. By using the list the error is fixed!

Comment: Whilst this does get rid of the error, for me this breaks the weighting for each class  produces worse results. I'd check for consistency before switching to a list.